# reposync/createrepo or rsync for mirroring a yum repository?

Tags: rsync, yum, rpm, reposync

In the redhat docs there is this howto https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016

It uses reposync and createrepo to mirror a repository server.

But you can also use rsync to just mirror the whole repository and you don't has to use createrepo (if I understand correctly).

So, please can someone tell me the difference between this two methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` mirrors a file-system and directory structure and requires that you have sufficient access to the file an directory layout on the source system. You may not have enough rights for that and also not every yum repository is a directory, yum repositories managed by for instance Red Hat's satellite server are backed by a database.

Therefore unlike `rsync` the more specific tool `reposync` will work for every yum repository.